# Django Rest Framework serializer returning decimal in scientific notation format

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm running drf 3.5 with django 1.10.2 and the regular end point view is working just fine, other than the fact my decimals are being converted to scientific notation format. I've made sure to define the decimal in the serializer to coerce_to_string=False.

So if I have a decimal like 0.000001 it will come down in json like 1e-06. but I have other decimals 0.032230 that come down from the server just fine. I'd prefer to not receive my decimals in scientific notation since I'd have to write some code on the fronted to convert the incoming decimals anytime i pull the data.

Comment: Does it come as `1e-06` or `"1e-06"`? The first one is already a valid number you don't need to convert it to anything.

Comment: only comes in 1e-06. I can tell js to convert it to a number just fine but I use schemas that fail with scientific notation.

Comment: i wonder if you have resolved it somehow ? having exactly the same issue

Comment: I never solved the issue, sorry.